# Why wont JavaScript work in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, alert

I was just testing some basic js code and chrome did not use it. 
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
 <body>
  <script src = "hi.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
alert("Hello");
```

I'm using a school owned Chromebook that's managed.

Comment: do you have a closing script tag? Any errors in the console?

Comment: I used a closing script tag.

Comment: And you put it inside head or body tag and make sure that javascript enabled for browser?

Comment: okay, now is there an error message in the [developer console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/?hl=en)?

Comment: No there is not an error in developer console and I put it in the body tag

Comment: What you have in the question will work provided `hi.js` is present and delivered correctly by the server. So my guess is it *is* being run, you're just not seeing the effect you expect to see, in which case we need to see `hi.js`.

Comment: Open your browser console, go to the “Network” panel. Do you see “hi.js” there? Is the path to that file correct or is there some networking error such as the file not being found?

Comment: Check if the js file is where you expect to be. Also, `<script src = "hi.js"></script>` could be the problem. Remove the spaces around `=`, so it becomes `<script src="hi.js"></script>`

Comment: As you have specified the JS file, it should be in the same directory as your HTML file.

Comment: Sorry, this may seem a dumb question (I started coding 2 month ago) but how do I do that beerwin?

Comment: If your HTML page is in `/folder/page.html` then your script should be in `/folder/hi.js`

Comment: @beerwin: Spaces around the `=` in attributes are **explicitly** supported in the specification, and have worked in browsers since I first started working with HTML in 1995.

Comment: Does the webserver allow access to js files (it usually does by default) or is that disabled in the web server config?

Comment: Yes, I did enable JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your code and it works fine.

The only thing that you could do wrong is place the hi.js file not in the same folder as the html file.

Did you already check that?

Comment: I dont know how to

Comment: Yes I did, it is in the same folder

Comment: Nope, but I realized why, I am on a monitored computer that does not allow sources in html

Comment: And the folder thing helped to =)